# How can I load padded JSONp as a non-executable, e.g. a string or data like regular JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, jsonp

I may have a thorny problem coming up due to a complex mix up in organisational release cycles between teams and organisations. Obviously I'm working for a better long term solution to the underlying problem, but I may have to handle a brief period (between a few days and a month, depending on organisational factors out of my control) where some client-side javascript needs to access some JSON from a source that simultaneously:

- Only serves it padded like for jsonp, for example:

  ```
  window['callback']({ "key": "value", "more": ["json", "data" ] });
  ```
- Only serves it with a json (non-executable) MIME type, with no_sniff, which means Chrome and various other browsers will block it from being executed as a javascript function call.

Is it possible for me to load it as if it was a flat text file, like I would if it was a CSV, as a string? Then I could chop off the jsonp padding with simple regexs then parse the string as JSON.

The libraries jQuery and D3 are available already for this, both of which have file loading features.

Most of the requests will be coming from the same domain, but I also need to cover some cases where a call may come from a different subdomain. I don't personally have direct access to server-side configuration but might be able to get some simple changes made by people who do in time.

Comment: Is the JSONP server on the same origin as your page? (If so, just fetch it with AJAX normally and read it.) If not, can you configure the JSONP-sending server to serve [CORS headers](http://enable-cors.org/)? Or can you set up a reverse proxy that fetches the resource server-side and then re-serves it on the same origin as the page? Those are the typical solutions.

Comment: Good point, I forgot to say. It's mostly same origin but might need to be accessed between different subdomains on the same domain. I've added a little on this.

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter suggests, what I would do is to build a simple server-side proxy which fetches the data and serves it back with the required specs, being them CORS headers or anything else you need.
This assumes you have access to an environment capable of running this tool.
Apart from this or having the headers changed by someone else, you don't have other choices...